# Storing autocad files in database

Tags: java, database, autocad

I have a client requirement in which I am asked to link autocad files with a table in DB. The file names will be stored in this table. This DB will be in the AWS cloud. The files will be mostly read only and downloaded by customers from the cloud.

Here's what is needed - 
Need to show a huge list of equipment's 
Each row will show equipment name, description and will show 3 options

Option 1 Download drawing file 
Option 2 Download pdf manual for this equipment 
Option 3 Download file which contains Unique ID for this equipment

I am not sure how to go about this. My questions to everyone reading this are as follows -
1. Should I be storing autocad files in a DB table or should I keep them in a folder and refer to them as and when needed?
2. If I should be storing it in a DB which database and datatype should I use?
3. Can someone tell me how I should go about implementing this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is discussion on the pros and cons of storing large files in a db: [Is it a bad practice to store large files (10 MB) in a database?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database).

I would suggest either storing fs locations in the db or using a JCR implementation (example [Apache jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org)) to manage your files.